# How to split on hyphen after splitted by comma?

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following input string: `Panama-Eduardo, Colombia-Elena`

I split the string at the comma using

```
String[] arr = input.split(",");
```

This results in

```
arr[0] = "Panama-Eduardo"
arr[1] = "Colombia-Elena"
```

My question is: How can I split those strings afterwards at the hyphen sothat I get the following result:

Group 1:

- `Panama`
- `Eduardo`

Group 2:

- `Colombia`
- `Elena`

Answer (score 3):

You just call `split` again. E.g.:

```
List<String[]> result = Arrays.stream(input.split(","))
    .map(s -> s.split("-"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @ito2307gm not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "split in order"?

Comment: Okay i divide it with comma in order for example Panama-Eduardo, Elena-Colombia, Elias-Chiriqui are three groups  the result is 
Group 1 
Panama
Eduardo
Group 2
Elena
Colombia
Group 3 
Elias
Chiriqui

Comment: @ito2307gm yes, the order is preserved.

Comment: Do i need import something for List and Arrays?

Comment: @ito2307gm `java.util.List` and `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: how can i print it ?
for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
     System.out.println(result[i]);
    }

Comment: @ito2307gm : You can print with the code :         for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(result.get(i)[0].trim());
            System.out.println(result.get(i)[1].trim());
        }

Comment: @ito2307gm : you need to import java.util.stream.Collectors;

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array to split it more.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : arr) {
    list.add(s.split("-"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please run the below code:

```
public class SplitExplained {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Panama-Eduardo, Colombia-Elena";
        String[] names = input.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            String[] strings = names[i].split("-");
            System.out.println("Group " + (i + 1));
            System.out.println(" ." + strings[0].trim());
            System.out.println(" ." + strings[1].trim());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```